# Postgis ST_DWithin query running slow

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have data of real time transit bus location and bus stop times and locations. They're divided into two tables:

**vehicle_position_trips** (approx <del>3</del> 10 million records, realtime position data including lat/lon point coordinates)

**stop_time_locations** (approx <del>1</del> 4 million records, bus stop locations including lat/lon point coordinates and bus stop times)

**I'm trying to find all vehicle positions that are within 15m of the bus stops for a particular bus route and the query is not using indexes and is running quite slow**

I'm using ST_Dwithin and the following query:

```sql
SELECT T.trip_id, T.ROUTEMAJOR
FROM vehicle_position_trips as T
INNER JOIN stop_time_locations as X
ON ST_DWithin(T.geog, X.geog, 25)
WHERE T.trip_id = X.trip_id AND T.trip_id IS NOT NULL AND T.ROUTEMAJOR = 4
```

Using the point coordinates for each table I created a geography column for each table along with a spatial index

```sql
ALTER TABLE vehicle_position_trips ADD COLUMN geog geography(POINT,4326);
UPDATE vehicle_position_trips SET geog = ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')');
CREATE INDEX vehicle_position_geog_idx ON vehicle_position_trips USING gist(geog);
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE stop_time_locations ADD COLUMN geog geography(POINT,4326);
UPDATE stop_time_locations SET geog = ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(' || stop_lon || ' ' || stop_lat || ')');
CREATE INDEX stop_times_geog_idx ON stop_time_locations USING gist(geog);
```

I also created an index for `trip_id` for both tables:

```sql
CREATE INDEX positions_trip_id_idx ON vehicle_position_trips(trip_id);
CREATE INDEX stops_trip_id_idx ON stop_time_locations(trip_id);
```

This is the result I get from EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```sql
  - Gather  (cost=125964.43..445659.67 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=1978.543..2610.686 rows=5859 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=124964.43..444659.57 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=1971.782..2506.291 rows=1953 loops=3)
        Hash Cond: (t.trip_id = x.trip_id)
        Join Filter: ((t.geog && _st_expand(x.geog, '15'::double precision)) AND (x.geog && _st_expand(t.geog, '15'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(t.geog, x.geog, '15'::double precision, true))
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 670155
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on vehicle_position_trips t  (cost=0.00..257701.18 rows=6961 width=40) (actual time=205.792..880.096 rows=14423 loops=3)
              Filter: ((trip_id IS NOT NULL) AND (routemajor = 10))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 3360183
        ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=93174.97..93174.97 rows=1564997 width=40) (actual time=1012.117..1012.117 rows=1249653 loops=3)
              Buckets: 65536  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 2816kB
.97 rows=1564997 width=40) (actual time=50.692..314.688 rows=1249653 loops=3)
Planning Time: 15.059 ms
Execution Time: 2611.505 ms
(15 rows)
```

Is there anything I can do to get this to run faster and why isn't it using any indexes?

Comment: Did you run `VACUUM ANALYZE tablename;` after creating the indexes?

Comment: Yes I did run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on both tables. Performance is still the same.

Comment: Your EXPLAIN  seems to be a bit mangled.  The row that starts with '.97' can't be correct and complete, for example.

Comment: For exploratory purposes, do a `set enable_seqscan=off;` and rerun the EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Comment: I did `set enable_seqscan=off;`. Looks like it's using indexes now but the execution time is still the same...

Comment: Did you eventually speed up your query? I am also having performance issues with `ST_DWithin`.